# "May I know did we participate this congress before?" or "May I know we participated before?"

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Which sentence is better?

> "May I know did we participate this congress before?"

or

> May I know we participated before?"

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences have mistakes in them. I fixed them here. They are both perfectly acceptable:

> May I know, did we participate ***in*** this congress before?
>
> May I know, ***have*** we participated ***in*** this congress before?

The first question is past tense. The second question is present perfect. They are both fine grammatically, but they have slighly different meanings.

You can learn about present perfect tense here: https://englishlive.ef.com/blog/english-grammar-help-present-perfect-and-past-perfect/